# SCSS nth-child in for loop?

Tags: variables, for-loop, sass

I was trying to create a loop to create a number of nth-child selectors with matching content:

```
$show-numbers: true;

@if $show-numbers {
  @for $i from 1 through 5 {
    &:nth-child(1) {
      &:before {
        content: '#{$i}';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This, of course, makes 5 copies of

```
ul.checkout-bar li:nth-child(1):before {
   content: "1";
}
```

with the "content" correctly incremented.  But I cannot get the nth-child value to increment.  Is this not possible in Sass?

**NOTE** a *static* variable can be interpolated:

```
$foo: 1;
    &:nth-child(#{$foo}) {
      &:before {
        content: '1';
      }
    }
```

This works fine.  It's the first thing I tried.

However, when using the `$i` in the `for` loop, it does not work.

Comment: It is NOT a duplicate.  That refers to a single use of the variable.  My question is about the auto-incrementing  variable in a FOR loop.  The answer at your link does NOT work, I already tried that.

Comment: Considering you aren't even referencing a variable in your selector, I'd say you haven't tried it.  Also, the output you claim you're getting is not possible from the provided code.

Comment: http://codepen.io/smlombardi/pen/LVPMzG?editors=110

There's the output, and proof for you I "tried it"

Comment: I might have made a typo somewhere, I swear the first 5 times I tried this in sassmeister it threw an error. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to wrap the `$i` as an integer in the `:nth-child()` like this:

```
$show-numbers: true;

@if $show-numbers {
  @for $i from 1 through 5 {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      &:before {
        content: '#{$i}';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Renders:

```
:nth-child(1):before {
    content:'1';
}

:nth-child(2):before {
    content:'2';
}

:nth-child(3):before {
    content:'3';
}

:nth-child(4):before {
    content:'4';
}

:nth-child(5):before {
    content:'5';
}
```

Comment: Please do not answer duplicate questions.